# getSheet(sheetName) causes OutofMemory Problems

Tags: java, jxl

I'm using `workbook.getSheet(sheetName)`  to get a specific sheet in an excel file and keep getting an OutOfMemory exception. The sheet has ~52000 rows.

Is there a way to read small chunks of the sheet or something to fix this? Note that increasing JVM memory is not really an option right now.

Comment: Which excel library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
setPropertySets(false);
```

> Sets whether or not to enable any
>   property sets (such as macros) to be
>   copied along with the workbook Leaving
>   this feature enabled will result in
>   the JXL process using more memory

Aside from that if you're operating on a single sheet, there isn't much else you can do besides giving your Java process more memory.